# Docker Build Error: Unrecognized Environment Variable from .env File within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables, containers

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build a Docker image, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B
 => [internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 2B
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: base name (${BASE_IMAGE}) should not be blank
```

I'm using Docker Compose to manage my Docker setup, and I've defined a `BASE_IMAGE` variable in my `.env` file. Here's a simplified version of my Dockerfile and Docker Compose configuration:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Read environment variables from .env file
ARG BASE_IMAGE

# Set base image
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

# Other Dockerfile instructions...
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
```

And here's what my `.env` file looks like:

```
BASE_IMAGE=python:3.6.6-alpine3.7
# Other environment variables...
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. It seems to be related to the `BASE_IMAGE` variable. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it to successfully build my Docker image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the build argument used in the Dockerfile using the `args` keyword. Also it's unnecessary to use `env_file` in this case.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${BASE_IMAGE}
    #env_file:
    #  - .env
```

Comment: I wanted to use a file where I declare the base image and other env variables so do I just do something like `BASE_IMAGE: python:3.6.6-alpine3.7` in the Docker compose file?

Comment: Hi yes you could either define the BASE_IMAGE argument statically in your ‘docker-compose.yml’ as you propose or you could have a ‘.env’ file which defines the value for BASE_IMAGE. I was just saying you don’t need to use the ‘env_file’ keyword, which is for setting the environment for the commands run within your docker container, as opposed to setting the values for variables interpreted by docker compose itself.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/) helpful in distinguishing between build arguments and environment variables.